# Imagem não aparece na view, em ambiente de produção

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Tenho o caminho das imagens salvas no banco, e as imagens numa pasta dentro da pasta public (nomeProjecto/public/imagem-post/post_id_2.jpg). em ambiente de desenvolvimento, aparece normalmente na view. Mas em ambiente de produção não aparece, mas o caminho da imagem é salvo no banco.

Outro pormenor é que as imagens que já foram gravadas no banco antes de hospedar o site, aparecem normalmente.

Ajudem-me por favor. Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score -2):

Se você está utilizando Laravel, você deve utilizar o método de `asset()` para pegar imagens como mostra na documentação.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem

Verifique também se seu framework está configurado para reconhecer a pasta onde você está salvando suas imagens.

Comment: Como faria esta verificação do framework?

Comment: Coloquei o método asset(), mas continua na mesma, não aparece nada.

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/272951)

Comment: Para verificar a configuração é só ir em `config/filesystems.php`
Por padrão o Laravel usa a pasta `storage/app/public`
Para te ajudar, clica com o botão direito do seu mouse em cima da imagem quebrada, depois em `inspecionar elemento` e veja qual caminho está no seu `src`

Comment: @veroneseComS a resposta é "usar o método `asset()`" e para usar esse e qualquer outro recurso o correto é SEMPRE recorretar à documentação.